# How can I correctly make signals in django 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, web, signals

I have users app written on django3(python 3.8). and model Profile which is extending User model. So i wanna do that each time when user creates account, django automaticly makes Profile for this. I have signals.py file on user app:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender = User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user = instance)
@receiver(post_save, sender = User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

and it's my users/apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'
        
    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

All working, no exceptions, errors. But It doesnt create profiles for new users.
note:

1. i had wrote `print()` in the `ready` method. But it doesnt print.
2. When i make profile in admin site, there are no problem. But why signals doesnt work?

Comment: how did you create the `User` instances?

Comment: Also, the `save_profile(...)` signal is irrelevant, it is doing nothing

Comment: @AzizNadirov did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if you have changed your User model or trying to use some other model as your user model, don't forget to Add line `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'` to your `settings.py` (change the 'users.User' to path of your User's app) to tell Django that you're using another model instead of default user model. Then in your signal instead of `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` try `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model` and change your codes to something like:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile


User = get_user_model()


@receiver(post_save, sender = User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user = instance)
```

Finally if you have already done these steps and you're signals still doesn't work try to add the following line in your `__init__.py` of your `users` app:

```
default_app_config = 'users.apps.UsersConfig'
```